# go to a new link in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, redirect

suppose I want to go a new link like www.facebook.com. How do I do this in laravel 4. If i use `return Redirect::to()` then I get the error that

> there is no method called www.facebook.com

in my controller. If I use `header('Location: ' . $url);` then I get the error

> Undefined variable: content

since there is a code in my controller which says `protected $layout = 'sites.master'` in in the layouts/master file there is a `{{$content}}`

Comment: `return Redirect::to('http://www.facebook.com');` should work.

Comment: let me try it. one second.

Comment: thank you very much. I don't know why it didn't work the first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `URL::route('named_route')')` function inside the href attribute in the blade syntax to go to a particular named route and `URL::to('link_adress')` function inside the href attribute in the blade syntax to go a particular custom address.
Example code for creating a link to google would be like:

```
<a class="link" href="{{ URL::to('http://www.google.com') }}">Go to google</a>
```

The view should use the blade templating engine for this to work.